# DB2 Select query for clob column comparison

Tags: db2, compare, clob

I have a table with below structure -

Table Name - Employee
Columns  - Id (Number) , Data(clob)

and my clob data is like :
{
"premium1":540,
"premium2":650,
"totalpremium":540
}

Now I want to select all the rows where totalpremium is either equal to premium1 or premium2.
Can someone help me with the SQL query

Comment: Yes, I can. Look into storing the data as JSON or to convert your data blob to JSON and use one of the built-in JSON functions. For more help, add the query you researched and you need specific help with.

Comment: If you are sure that `data` is always a well-formed JSON document, then you can store it as `BSON` (binary JSON) instead of `CLOB`. Then, it's easier to manipulate and extract data.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't configured for your table but, as an example, it might provide the syntax you need:

SELECT
JSON_VALUE(jsondata, 'strict $.logbook_key' RETURNING INTEGER) AS logbook_key
,JSON_VALUE(jsondata, 'strict $.brakes_off' RETURNING TIMESTAMP) AS brakes_off
,JSON_VALUE(jsondata, 'strict $.from' RETURNING CHAR(4)) AS from_airfield
from activity_data
WHERE JSON_VALUE(jsondata, 'strict $.from' RETURNING CHAR(4)) = 'EGBT' ;
;

Regards
Mark

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your CLOB value looks like well formatted json document.
So, you can use the [JSON_VALUE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-json-value) function to extract particular element values like below.

```
WITH Employee (Id, Data) AS
(
VALUES 
  (1, '{ "premium1":540, "premium2":650, "totalpremium":540 }')
, (2, '{ "premium1":540, "premium2":650, "totalpremium":  0 }')
)
SELECT *
FROM Employee 
WHERE 
  JSON_VALUE (Data, 'strict $.totalpremium' RETURNING INT)
  IN 
  (
    JSON_VALUE (Data, 'strict $.premium1' RETURNING INT)
  , JSON_VALUE (Data, 'strict $.premium2' RETURNING INT) 
  )

|ID |DATA                                                  |
|---|------------------------------------------------------|
|1  |{ "premium1":540, "premium2":650, "totalpremium":540 }|
```